#  display on layout android

Tags: android, image

I want to download image from server and display them into a layout

EXAMPLE INSTAGRAM APPLICATION android

So what can I take for this
using table layout 
or using image gallery
and only few image display first when i scroll other images load
how is possible

click on this [link](http://www.google.co.in/imgres?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=lAq&sa=X&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&biw=1600&bih=771&tbm=isch&prmd=imvnsa&tbnid=CwL1llGfp2QJbM%3a&imgrefurl=http://blog.appboy.com/2010/10/5-things-instagram-got-right-that-others-before-it-couldnt/&docid=gDrrXMQHVCT6RM&imgurl=http://blog.appboy.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/instagram-popular-1.jpg&w=320&h=480&ei=euegT8yoDoSzrAfkqLj2CA&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=1287&vpy=150&dur=491&hovh=128&hovw=90&tx=108&ty=126&sig=107909598838583184261&page=1&tbnh=128&tbnw=90&start=0&ndsp=40&ved=1t:429,r:8,s:0,i:87) and you'll understand what I want to do.

Comment: you need to search Lazy Loading in android for Images .

Comment: lazy loading is right but click on below link and you understand what i want

Comment: clik here this google link <http://www.google.co.in/imgres?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=lAq&sa=X&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&biw=1600&bih=771&tbm=isch&prmd=imvnsa&tbnid=CwL1llGfp2QJbM:&imgrefurl=http://blog.appboy.com/2010/10/5-things-instagram-got-right-that-others-before-it-couldnt/&docid=gDrrXMQHVCT6RM&imgurl=http://blog.appboy.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/instagram-popular-1.jpg&w=320&h=480&ei=euegT8yoDoSzrAfkqLj2CA&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=1287&vpy=150&dur=491&hovh=128&hovw=90&tx=108&ty=126&sig=107909598838583184261&page=1&tbnh=128&tbnw=90&start=0&ndsp=40&ved=1t:429,r:8,s:0,i:87>

Comment: you can use same Lazy Loading concept with `GridView` to get desire result.

Comment: thanks herry now i understand

Comment: you can start search Lazy Loading with `GridView` in android ,that will really help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class AndroidWebImage extends Activity {

//Android Bitmap Image

/*String image_URL=
 "http://4.bp.blogspot.com/_C5a2qH8Y_jk/StYXDpZ9-WI/AAAAAAAAAJQ/sCgPx6jfWPU/S1600-R/android.png";*/

// QR Code Image URL

String image_URL =
    "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=200x200&cht=qr&chl=http%3A%2F%2Fandroid-er.blogspot.com%2F";
   /** Called when the activity is first created. */
   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);

       ImageView bmImage = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.image);
    BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions;
    bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;
    Bitmap bm = LoadImage(image_URL, bmOptions);
    bmImage.setImageBitmap(bm);
   }

   private Bitmap LoadImage(String URL, BitmapFactory.Options options)
   {       
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream in = null;       
       try {
           in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
           bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
           in.close();
       } catch (IOException e1) {
       }
       return bitmap;               
   }

private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String strURL) throws IOException{
 InputStream inputStream = null;
 URL url = new URL(strURL);
 URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

 try{
  HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)conn;
  httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
  httpConn.connect();

  if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
   inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
  }
 }
 catch (Exception ex)
 {
 }
 return inputStream;
}

}
```

Comment: And how exactly does your answer solve "only few image display first when i scroll other images load" this problem?

Comment: this example loads single image from the server and display it in ImageView

Comment: You should have mentioned that in the answer. Just writing code doesn't 'answer' a question (in this case it doesn't even answer the entire question). Where code is definitely helpful(I always encourage people to attach code snippets with their answer), it is still easier to read english.

Comment: Did you add the Internet permission in Menifest?? @Aki what you want to say??

Comment: just chek this link <http://www.google.co.in/imgres?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=lAq&sa=X&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&biw=1600&bih=771&tbm=isch&prmd=imvnsa&tbnid=CwL1llGfp2QJbM:&imgrefurl=http://blog.appboy.com/2010/10/5-things-instagram-got-right-that-others-before-it-couldnt/&docid=gDrrXMQHVCT6RM&imgurl=http://blog.appboy.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/instagram-popular-1.jpg&w=320&h=480&ei=euegT8yoDoSzrAfkqLj2CA&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=1287&vpy=150&dur=491&hovh=128&hovw=90&tx=108&ty=126&sig=107909598838583184261&page=1&tbnh=128&tbnw=90&start=0&ndsp=40&ved=1t:429,r:8,s:0,i:87>

Comment: hey krishnakant your code is work for single image download thanks but what can i do for multiple images chek i add a link in my question so u can understand and tell me what can i do for that

Comment: i want this chek link <http://www.google.co.in/imgres?hl=en&client=firefox-a&hs=lAq&sa=X&rls=org.mozilla:en-US:official&biw=1600&bih=771&tbm=isch&prmd=imvnsa&tbnid=CwL1llGfp2QJbM:&imgrefurl=http://blog.appboy.com/2010/10/5-things-instagram-got-right-that-others-before-it-couldnt/&docid=gDrrXMQHVCT6RM&imgurl=http://blog.appboy.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/10/instagram-popular-1.jpg&w=320&h=480&ei=euegT8yoDoSzrAfkqLj2CA&zoom=1&iact=hc&vpx=1287&vpy=150&dur=491&hovh=128&hovw=90&tx=108&ty=126&sig=107909598838583184261&page=1&tbnh=128&tbnw=90&start=0&ndsp=40&ved=1t:429,r:8,s:0,i:87>

Comment: Async task What you are searching for. Go through this Link and learn what Async task is. This is not exact what you are searching but you will achieve your target with little efforts. http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html